# Excel - Formula that Counts the First of each Duplicate

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that looks like follows:

[image: Spreadsheet]

On the lefthand side, column A, I have Bug numbers that corresponds to a specific bug in our Bugzilla.

I am trying to find a way to place, in a single cell, the amount of Bugs that have duplicates, each of them only counted **once**.

For example, say I have this:

```
Col A
1
1
2
3
3
3
4
4
5
```

I would like to have the formula return me **3** because I have 3 numbers that have duplicates, but each of them only counted once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use COUNTIF and SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF($A$1:$A$9,$A$1:$A$9)>1)/COUNTIF($A$1:$A$9,$A$1:$A$9))
```

[image]

To deal with blanks we need to use SUM(IF()) in an array:

```
=SUM(IF(((COUNTIF($A$1:$A$9,$A$1:$A$9)>1)*($A$1:$A$9<>"")),1/COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$9,$A$1:$A$9,$A$1:$A$9,"<>")))
```

being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: It seems to work! I just need to filter out blank spaces so I don't divide by zero. How would I do such a thing? I know it has to do with something like `<>""` or something. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: @Chakraa see edit, and please remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much :)